# Revise high school material

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, education, big-list

Can you suggest me a comprehensive book to revise high school mathematics (up to besic calculus)? It should be extremely clear and complete and "scientific" (not like most high school books). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are always the Math for dummies books that are easier to understand. Simply look up Pre-Calc for dummies or any other math subject and there will be a book on it. You can also find work books to practice what you learned in the books.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Simmons' Precalculus Mathematics in a Nutshell: Geometry, Algebra, Trigonometry and Stewart's Precalculus. Both are great books and have tons of problems.

Comment: you are answering a question that is 4 years old, Your time would be better spent answering current and open questions .

Comment: @TheIntegrator are you serious or joking? :/